# How to Invalidate Dojo/Require's Module Cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, dojo, requirejs

I have a dojo-based module that automates loading a dojo/store/Memory for me, using a bang. It's called like so:

```
require( [ 'squad_builder/storeBroker!collectionStore' ],
    function( collectionStore )
{ 
    // use store...
} );
```

The first require() call loads the store and subsequent ones load the store from a cache.

This works well but I cannot figure out how to invalidate require's internal cache so I can make the next request load the store with fresh data.

Is there anything built into require() to do this or do I need to mess with some internal workings (and if so, where?)

**Edit**

In [the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html#loader-amd) it mentions:

> Note: the dojo loader includes the nonstandard function require.undef,
>   which undefines a module value.

But that method is undefined when I call it. Looking at require() in Firebug with:

```
for( i in require )
{
    console.log( 'require', i, require[ i ] );
}
```

require.module has a `def()` method but not an `undef()` one.

**Edit 2**

`Require.cache` only seems to contain dojo and dijit modules. Where are custom namespaced modules cached?

Comment: May I ask why you chose that plugin design rather than using dojo/store/JsonRest to load fresh data from the server using queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dojo site, the function is not automatically included in "built" dojo files.  If you look at an uncompressed dojo.js you will see it there.
From:http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html

> The following table provides a list of options that are leveraged
>   within the loader. The first column is the Option/Feature as defined
>   within the loader, the second options is whether this is a detected
>   feature (via has.add()) or if it is just an option and its default
>   value. With “unbuilt” source, all the features and options are
>   available. If the loader has been built, then some of these features
>   may have been set as staticHasFeatures and not be configurable
>   anymore.

Also here it says that you might be able to turn the function back on by adding a line go djconfig
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/require-undef-td3990559.html

> dojoConfig = {    has : {
>         "dojo-undef-api": true    } }